# argparse positional, nargs='+', and default

Tags: python, argparse

While using argparse with positionals, and `default` provided, `nargs='*'` works as expected by setting the positional to the default if no positionals are provided. But `nargs='+'` does not do this. The default provided is a non-empty list, and it does get correctly shown in the help string in both cases, but the `default` is only used  when using `nargs='*'`.

Is my expectation wrong or is this a bug/inconsistency in argparse?

Program:

```py
import argparse

for narg in '*+':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=f'test nargs {narg}')
    parser.add_argument(
        'dir',
        nargs=narg,
        default=['dir_a', 'dir_b'],
        help='provide directories as arguments (default: %(default)s)',
    )
    try:
        args = parser.parse_args(['-h'])
    except SystemExit:
        pass 
    args = parser.parse_args([])
    print(f'>>>>> args {args}\n')
```

Output:

```
usage: testnargs.py [-h] [dir ...]

test nargs *

positional arguments:
  dir         provide directories as arguments (default: ['dir_a', 'dir_b'])

options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
>>>>> args Namespace(dir=['dir_a', 'dir_b'])

usage: testnargs.py [-h] dir [dir ...]

test nargs +

positional arguments:
  dir         provide directories as arguments (default: ['dir_a', 'dir_b'])

options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
usage: testnargs.py [-h] dir [dir ...]
testnargs.py: error: the following arguments are required: dir
```

The real-world program this problem arose in, reads in the defaults from an *optional* config file. So I don't know if there is always going to be a default, otherwise I could of course change the `'+'` into `'*'` permanently. For now I did change to `'*'`, and check down the line, but it is hassle.

This was run with Python 3.10.5 on MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not as involved with the `argparse` bug/issues as I used to be, but I don't consider this to be a bug.

Your help line is simply expanded as follows:

```
In [78]: help='provide directories as arguments (default: %(default)s'
In [79]: help%{'default': ['a','b']}
Out[79]: "provide directories as arguments (default: ['a', 'b']"
```

The relevant code methods from the source code are:

```
def _get_help_string(self, action):
    return action.help

def _expand_help(self, action):
    params = dict(vars(action), prog=self._prog)
    for name in list(params):
        if params[name] is SUPPRESS:
            del params[name]
    for name in list(params):
        if hasattr(params[name], '__name__'):
            params[name] = params[name].__name__
    if params.get('choices') is not None:
        choices_str = ', '.join([str(c) for c in params['choices']])
        params['choices'] = choices_str
    return self._get_help_string(action) % params
```

`help`, `default` etc are attributes of the argument's `Action` object.  It just does a `dict` format.  If the help has '{%default}' string, it is displayed.

The formatter variant that automatically adds `{%default}`, does test whether the `Action` is positional and whether the `nargs` allows for a meaningful `default`.

```
class ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter(HelpFormatter):
    """Help message formatter which adds default values to argument help.
    Only the name of this class is considered a public API. All the methods
    provided by the class are considered an implementation detail.
    """

    def _get_help_string(self, action):
        help = action.help
        if '%(default)' not in action.help:
            if action.default is not SUPPRESS:
                defaulting_nargs = [OPTIONAL, ZERO_OR_MORE]
                if action.option_strings or action.nargs in defaulting_nargs:
                    help += ' (default: %(default)s)'
        return help
```

Adding something to the `help` is easy.  Removing it in any reliable way is not (though you are welcome to write your own `_get_help_string` method to do so).  The default formatter formats the help as you specify.

Comment: What I expected is that the help text is correct, and that the code for `nargs='+'` should work with only a default value. But that is essentially how I want it to work. Since I generate the code for argparse from data, I can insert a piece that changes the nargs argument depending on the availability of a default

Comment: Default values are written to the Namespace at the start of parsing, and then overwritten as the argument is encountered.  A `positional` will always be encountered, or raise an `required argument` error.  Only '*' and '?' `positionals` get special treatment, since they are always "seen", even by 'nothing'.  So for a '+', a `default` is not a substitute for actually providing at least one value.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I agree that the default shouldn't be shown in the help text if it's not going to be used and in my opinion you should report this (and only this) as a bug.</s> (←not true, see comments)

But regarding the behavior itself, I don't think a default for `nargs='+'` makes sense as the whole point that differentiates it from `nargs='*'` is that it *requires* the user to provide at least one argument. If you have a default, you should just use `*`, and if you don't know if you have a default in advance as in your case, you could either first check if you have one and then set `nargs` depending on that or do what you're doing now by using `*` and applying the default afterwards.

Sorry that this isn't very helpful but I see no way around what you're already doing (or variants thereof).

Comment: `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` does not add a `%default` to the `help` when a default for a positional does not make sense (aa here).  Neither should the user. Don't expect the code to edit 'bad' help lines.

Comment: Sorry, I totally glossed over the fact that a help format string was provided explicitly. I agree that it's not a bug then.

Answer (score 1):

A comment block in argparse.py indicates:

> assuming that actions that use the default value don't really count as "present"

So contrary to my assumption that the "bug" is in argparse not accepting the default for `nargs='+'` the error is actually in the help formatter as @hpaulj indicated.

Since what I expected is essentially

> assuming that actions that have a default are always counted as "present"

I'll have to work around this. Since I generate the argparse code (using cligen) I can relatively easily build in some check that the argument to `nargs` changes from '+' to '*' if a default is provided. That would be a short-term solution, it is probably better to generate something simpler than argparse code, that will not generate these kind of surprises.

Comment: When constructing an `argparse` automatically, it might be best to use `optionals` (flagged) arguments.  One `positional` argument with '*' or '+' is ok, but it it hard to use a parser with more than one of those.  With `optionals`, defaults behave as you hope.